# Searching nodes - Libxml

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I am trying to parse an XML document in C++. I do not have any form of metadata associated with the document. Since i am a novice with XML's i wanted to understand the best way to parse this xml. I am using libxml2 to achive this.

What i am doing currently is 
1) walking the complete tree node by node , using pointers of the root node of document. 
2) Comparing & looking for the node i need , extracting the value. 
3) repeat 1-2;

Is this the best possible way to do it , constrained by the library ? I ran through the API , but could not find something that would fit the bill.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" probably depends on your application.  XPath is another alternative for finding a specific node or list of nodes.  libxml2 example code [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#xpath1.c) and [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#xpath2.c).

General XPath examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp).